# Equal Height Columns Using JS - Not working on Mobile Devices

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using JS to calculate height on three columns that contain text and images of various size.

Here is the JS I am using:

```
maxHeight = 0;
$('.equalheight').each(function() {
  maxHeight = Math.max(maxHeight, $(this).outerHeight());
});

$('.equalheight').css({ height: maxHeight + 'px' });
```

This works on the desktop in multiple browsers, however, it doesn't work on certain mobile devices. It works on my iPad Mini (latest iOS) but doesn't work on another's iPad 3 or iPhone. It also doesn't work on my Samsung Galaxy S4 using stock browser.

How do I solve this issue?

[Here is the site](http://www.checkplusbalance.com/) in question.

Comment: Could you provide a testcase (jsbin, jsfiddle)?

Comment: In your `each()` call try manually setting `maxHeight` to something like 400. If that doesn't work, you're one step closer to finding your bug.

Comment: @JoDavid - I added the site link, I don't have a fiddle created.

Comment: are you using a [meta viewport tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) on the mobile devices? by default phones lie and pretend that the visible screen real estate is a greater number of CSS pixels than the actual device pixels, which could be a factor

Comment: if you want equal heights columns, why not use css inline block on those elements instead

Comment: @Plato - I am using the following meta viewport tag: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a fiddle with @Huangism's suggestion of `inline-block`. You can adjust the column heights to experiment.
http://jsfiddle.net/6WZrM/4/

IF the container div has a fixed height, the columns will fill to that height. I'm setting that with js instead of the column heights directly. Perhaps this approach will work on your problem devices. Also worth considering is that you don't have `var` before your `maxHeight`, i suppose its possible that some devices treat its scope differently than others?

```
//css
#column1, #column2{
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
}

//js
var maxHeight = 0;
$('.equalheight').each(function() {
  maxHeight = Math.max(maxHeight, $(this).outerHeight());
});

$('#container').css({ height: maxHeight + 'px' });
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a jQuery plugin for this exact purpose: https://github.com/dubbs/equal-height

If you want to make all columns the same height, use:

```js
$('.equalheight').equalHeight();
```

If you want to group them by their top position, eg. within each container:

```js
$('.equalheight').equalHeight({ groupByTop: true });
```